# How to setup H2O spark using scala in Intellij?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

I am new to sparkling water.  I have been trying to develop project for it in intellij but couldnt.I couldnt find many resources for same on internet.
So any can please tell how to develop a simple project using h20 and spark in scala with IntelliJ.

I tried this code:

```
import org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.{h2o, SparkConf, SparkContext}
import water.H2OClientApp
import water.fvec._
import org.apache.spark.h2o._
object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("testing")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val source = getClass.getResource("data.txt")
    val distF = sc.textFile(source.getFile)
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    val table1 = distF.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6))).toDF()


    import org.apache.spark.h2o._
    val h2oContext = new H2OContext(sc).start()
    import h2oContext._
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

    val mydf2:h2o.RDD[Person] = h2oContext.createH2ORDD(table1)
    println("Count of mydf2================>>>>>>>>"+mydf2.count())

  }
}

case class Person(Country: String, ASN: String,Time_Stamp: String,Metric_A: String,Co_Server: String,Bytes: String,Send_Time:String);
```

And for this i got error.
Error part of log generated is:

```
15/12/24 03:45:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 17, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.H2ORDD$$anon$1.next(H2ORDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.H2ORDD$$anon$1.next(H2ORDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1555)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

15/12/24 03:45:53 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/12/24 03:45:53 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/12/24 03:45:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 16) on executor localhost: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (argument type mismatch) [duplicate 1]
15/12/24 03:45:53 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 5.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/12/24 03:45:53 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 5
15/12/24 03:45:53 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 5 (count at test.scala:32) failed in 0.038 s
15/12/24 03:45:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 5 failed: count at test.scala:32, took 0.050463 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 17, localhost): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.H2ORDD$$anon$1.next(H2ORDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.H2ORDD$$anon$1.next(H2ORDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1555)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1121)
    at test$.main(test.scala:32)
    at test.main(test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.H2ORDD$$anon$1.next(H2ORDD.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.H2ORDD$$anon$1.next(H2ORDD.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getIteratorSize(Utils.scala:1555)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$count$1.apply(RDD.scala:1121)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please let me know where I wnt wrong and what changes I have to do and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look also at https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/tree/master/sparkling-water-droplet

It provides a skeleton code for a simple Sparkling Water project. Also look at these lines: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/blob/master/sparkling-water-droplet/build.gradle#L34-L43 It allows you to configure dependencies on H2O and Spark.

I would recommend to use the latest version of Sparkling water - 1.5.9.

Regarding opening project in Idea - simply open `build.gradle` in Idea and follow Gradle project import wizard.

One more update: the droplet now contains also Sbt definition: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/blob/master/sparkling-water-droplet/build.sbt

Comment: To add to Michal's second point, make sure you have the scala plugin installed for intellij.  Then do this:

    `git clone https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water.git`; 
    `cd sparkling-water`;
    `./gradlew idea`;
    `open sparkling-water.ipr`

Comment: Thanks Michal.Can u tell me if this error is generated due to conversion of RDD to h2oRDD? or is this only due to configuration of dependency....

Comment: Can you please provide little bit information? Which Sparkling Water and Spark version are you using? From my user experience is better to use DataFrame instead of using strong-typed RDD.

Comment: i m using "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.1" and "sparkling-water-core_2.10" % "1.5.6"

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to create a Scala project in Intellij. Then you must set the dependencies inside the *build.sbt* file. Specifically:

```
name := "Your Project Name"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.5.1", 
"org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.1.5",
"javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.0.1",
"junit" % "junit" % "4.12",
"ai.h2o" % "sparkling-water-core_2.10" % "1.4.8"
)
assemblyOption in assembly := (assemblyOption in assembly).value.copy(includeScala = false)
```

Based on your spark version and the H2O version you can search over the Maven central repository and check which are compatible with both packages and download the respective.

You may not need the javax.servlet package in your case.

Moreover, for the assembly plugin, you have to declare the following inside the */project/plugins.sbt* file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
```

Then open the SBT tab (at the right of the Intellij window) and press the Refresh button (upper left corner).

Finally verify that everything is working by executing the number 4 from the below link: 
http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/sparkling-water/rel-1.4/9/index.html

Hope the above will help you.

Comment: Thanks  for the help.I tried with code(updated in question ) and got error(check log in question).Please let me know where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This happens mainly due to the type mismatch between input and the case class.

Comment: This is not the answer i guess it should have been on comment section.

Comment: I think the original question has diverged So I wrote answer according to Log `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch `